# want to have login page using jquery which will check for null input

Tags: jquery

I want one login page which will check for null user name and password using jquery, and use post method to cal servlet on submiting.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").click(function(){
      if(($("#name").val()=="")||($("#pass").val()=="")){
          alert("user name and pass cant be empty");
                     // location.reload();           
        }else{
            $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
                      {
                        name:$("#name"),
                        pass:$("#pass")
                      },
                      function(data,status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " +status);
                      });
                    });
        }
          });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>


<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ></p>
<p>password <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"></p>
<input type="submit" value="login" id="button">
```

Comment: -1 Even if jQuery validator can help, you must do server side validation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: @silviu server side validation to check  whether empty userlogin and password is sent?, what are you sayin bro,those fields should have some value.

Answer (score 0):

In the second part of the condition, you didn't use the double `==` for comparison:

```
if(($("#name").val()=="")||($("#pass").val()="")){
//                                          ^ should be ==
```

Change to:

```
if(($("#name").val()=="")||($("#pass").val()=="")){
//                                          ^ fixed
```